# Problem Getting Gradients when using a Scipy function in pytorch

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch, gradient

I've gone through the example on this pytorch page: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/numpy_extensions_tutorial.html

In the second example they use a scipy function `scipy.signal.convolve2d`, I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.quad`.

Here is the forward function in a pytorch module from the example where the input is a tensor that requires grad, after using this function to get the output they are still able to compute gradients on the input variable. This is what I'm trying to do. Notice the use of `detach` here on the inputs.

```
class ScipyConv2dFunction(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, filter, bias):
        # detach so we can cast to NumPy
        input, filter, bias = input.detach(), filter.detach(), bias.detach()
        result = correlate2d(input.numpy(), filter.numpy(), mode='valid')
        result += bias.numpy()
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, filter, bias)
        return torch.as_tensor(result, dtype=input.dtype)
```

example code:

```
module = ScipyConv2d(3, 3)
print("Filter and bias: ", list(module.parameters()))
input = torch.randn(10, 10, requires_grad=True)
output = module(input)
print("Output from the convolution: ", output)
output.backward(torch.randn(8, 8))
print("Gradient for the input map: ", input.grad)
```

So I feel like I'm trying to do the same thing except with a different scipy function, `quad` and I think it should work. Here is the code

```
t_list = torch.tensor([0])
U = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True )

def pytorch_objective(u):
  global U
  return torch.log(U) + torch.as_tensor( integrate.quad(func, t_list[-1].numpy() , u.detach().numpy() )[0] )

initial_x = torch.tensor([4.], requires_grad = True) 
value = pytorch_objective(initial_x)
value.backward()
print(initial_x.grad)
```

And at the end it prints out `None`. I can confirm that if I simplify the objective function to not use scipy, we don't `detach` the tensor and just do some basic computation, that the gradient **does** work as expected. Of course, I think when we `detach` the variable `u` (`initial_x`) it seems we would lose the gradients for it.

Does anyone know if I'm on the wrong track here?

Comment: You didn't implement a backward method. In the pytorch example they implement a custom backward function. This is absolutely necessary when you leave the pytorch framework (e.g. when you detach and/or convert to numpy in the middle). I would recommend you read through the [Extending `torch.autograd`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html) documentation which explains why this is the case. My initial impression looking at your code is that an approximate backward method could be implemented by considering the first fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @jodag thanks so much, also for the tip about the FTC. I think what you're saying is that if I were to make a new PyTorch function for the Scipy Quad function, then I need to implement the `backward` method which returns the gradient of the input. With the FTC it seems the gradient of this input is just the function itself evaluated at the input. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, you need to manually program the backward to return the gradient and yes, i was thinking your gradient is basically a direct application of FTC.

Comment: Holy Sh** it worked, that's awesome! As you may have guessed this is an optimization algo (Newton Algorithm) so I can compare to my non-pytorch code and it matches perfectly no with the pytorch implementation of the scipy quad function!